# Add submenu page to a custom menu page

Tags: custom-post-types, wp-editor, add-menu-page, add-submenu-page

For a company project I'm fully customizing the wordpress wp-admin dashboard to be the front end after an user is logged in. I need to hide the admin bar for non admin users and add a submenù to a custom menù page I have added, at the moment this is my code to add the menù page

```php
function add_custom_menu(){
        add_menu_page( 
            'Comunications', 
            'Comunications', 
            'read', 
            'messages', 
            array( $this, 'render_messages_page' ), 
            'data:image/svg+xml;base64,...', 
            3
        );
}
```

Using add action I'm able to load the custom page that is created using a php file that I'm requiring into the callback function. I've created a custom post type that will be used for this kind of menù and I'm registering it using this code:

```php
        register_post_type( 
            'comunications', 
            array(
                'label' => 'Comunications',
                'labels' => 'Comunications',
                'description' => 'Internal Comunications System',
                'menu_icon' => 'dashicons-rss',
                'public' => true,
                'hierarchical' => false,
                'publicy_queryable' => true,
                'show_ui' => false,
                'show_in_nav_menus' => false,
                'show_in_rest' => true,
                'supports' => array( 'title', 'editor', 'thumbnail', 'revisions' ),
                'has_archive' => true,
                'exclude_from_search' => false
            )
        );
```

Also this will work, but at the moment since I've a custom wp menù where I've removed all the default WordPress pages for non admin, I'm not able to see this cpt. My idea is to add it as a submenù under the menù page I've created so users with right permissions will have the ability to create a new comunication using the standard wordpress way, this beacuse at the moment into the custom page I'm using I've called the `wp_editor()` function and I'm not sure if I can save the content under this cpt, this is the custom page code

```
<?php 
    $q = new WP_Query(
            array(
                'post_type' => 'comunications',                    
                'posts_per_apge' => 4
            )
        );
?>
    <div class="container-fluid mt-5 px-5">
        <div class="row m-0">
            <div class="col-12">
                <h4 class="text-uppercase fw-bold">
                    Last comunications
                </h4>
            </div>
            <?php if( $q->have_posts() ) : while( $q->have_posts() ) : the_post(); ?>
                <div class="col-3">
                    <div class="card">
                        <img class="card-img-top" src="<?php esc_url( the_post_thumbnail_url() ); ?>">
                        <div class="card-body">
                        
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>   
            <?php endwhile; endif; wp_reset_postdata(); ?>
        </div>
        <?php if( current_user_can( 'manage_options' ) ) : ?>
            <div class="row m-0">
                <div class="col-12">
                    <hr class="my-3">
                </div>
                <div class="col-12">
                    <h4 class="text-uppercase fw-bold">
                        Send comunication
                    </h4>
                </div>
                <div class="col-8 mb-3">
                    <label class="fw-bold text-uppercase mb-2">
                        Subject
                    </label>
                    <input type="text" class="form-control" name="" placeholder="Subject">
                </div>
                <div class="col-4 mb-3">
                    <label class="fw-bold text-uppercase mb-2">
                        Receivers
                    </label>
                    <div class="input-group w-100">
                        <select class="form-select" name="" >
                            <option>-</option>
                        </select>
                        <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary text-uppercase" id="">
                            Pubblica
                        </button>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="col-12">
                    <?php 
                        wp_editor( 
                            '', 
                            'comunication-editor',
                            array(
                                'media_buttons' => true,
                                //'textarea_rows' => 30,
                                'quicktags' => false
                            ) 
                        ); 
                    ?>
                </div>
            </div>
        <?php endif; ?>
    </div>
<?php
```

Any suggestion on how add the submenu page or on how to save the editor content as a cpt with the actual code?